# Jasmine waitsFor throws error on timeout - Expected a spy, but got Function

Tags: javascript, jasmine, karma-runner

When testing asynchronous behavior, I run the following waitsFor/run pairing. I expect that Jasmine would print the error message - "should have returned true" - and continue, but it crashes and throws an error instead. The error reads "Uncaught Error: Expected a spy, but got Function."

This occurs in Jasmine version 1.5 on line 1442 using the Karma test runner through grunt. There is no other references in the stack trace.

I checked the documentation several times and have been using waitsFor/runs for a few months. What am I missing?

```
waitsFor(function() {
    return false;
}, 'should have returned true', 1750);

runs(function() {
    expect(0).toBe(0);
});
```

Edit: Note that when the waitsFor function returns true instead, the test passes and testing continues.

Comment: Can you reproduce this in a fiddle/plunker?

Comment: Sorry I didn't,  I was hoping someone would know what would break testing in conjunction with this snippet.

What ended up being the problem was that early in testing, I wrote a setTimeout as opposed to waitsFor/runs. I think karma did some garbage collection before setTimeout executed its callback, and the expect clause in the callback threw an error.